# Solving tethering issue on Windows Phone 8

Tags: internet-sharing

I cannot start internet sharing on my Nokia Lumia 520.

From the menu I choose:

Settings -> Internet Sharing -> On

I get this error:

Connection not shared
Internet sharing isn't currently available.

Comment: AT&T also requires $$ for this feature. I pay an extra $25/month for the ability to share internet. It does give me an extra 3 gigs of data though to soften the hit.

Comment: Dude, if you already subscribe to any data plan, and you face this problem, you are not alone. I'm face this issue as well. But what I did is restart the phone, then it works. :) Try this.

Comment: @jefferyleo you should post that as an answer instead so that this question can be answered.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed with the newest Windows Phone 8 update. It had nothing to do with the carrier block or the internet sharing plan.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a carrier block.

Maybe you need to have an internet sharing plan.

As far as I know Verizon is one of many that blocks this feature until you change your plan.

It is important to know from where you bought your phone and not the currently carrier.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem this week. My plan through AT&T includes data sharing, and the feature was working fine for some time.  But I got an OS update on my HTC One M8, and it suddenly stopped working. When I tried to turn it on, I would get the same message as the original poster: "Internet sharing isn't currently available"

I restarted my phone (power off, then back on) and it is working again.